# Binding method to instance

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Is there a way to bind an existing method to an existing instance of an object if both the method and the instance are passed as symbols into a method that does that if the instance is not a symbol?

For example:

```
    def some_method
      #do something
    end

    some_instance = Klass.new(something)

    def method_that_binds(:some_method, to: :some_instance)
      #how do I do that?
    end
```

Comment: An example of how you would call/use the method that accepts the symbols would be helpful.

Comment: This still seems like an XY problem to me. I can't think of any reason why you would ever need to pass a local variable _name_, rather than the local variable itself.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the answer is NO! It seems like you want to take an instance method from class `A` and make it an instance method of class `B`. Is that correct? Consider that when that method is invoked on an instance of `A` it can inspect instance variables, invoke other methods of `A`, etc.  None of that would be possible for an instance of `B`. If you could do that, presumably you could add the method `String#downcase` to the class `Hash`, to allow you to "dowcase hashes"! But as I said before, perhaps I've misunderstood the question. If so please clarify by editing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: The requirement that methods can only be bound to instances of their `owner` has been lifted sometime between 2.0 and 2.2. But actually, that is irrelevant here, since the OP's method is a "global" method, i.e. an instance method of `Object`, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are a little unusual, but it is possible to do this mostly as you say:

```
class Person; end
harry = Person.new
barry = Person.new

def test
  puts 'It works!'
end

define_method :method_that_binds do |a_method, to|
  eval(to[:to].to_s).singleton_class.send(:define_method, a_method, &Object.new.method(a_method))
end

method_that_binds :test, to: :harry
harry.test
# It works! will be sent to STDOUT
barry.test
# undefined method 'test'
```

This doesn't actually use a named parameter, but accepts a hash with a `to` key, but you can see you can call it in the way you want. It also assumes that the methods you are defining are defined globally on `Object`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the `block`?

Comment: No. It has to be in `method_that_binds`. It has to be something like Rails' `delegate` but I can't use the original.

Comment: Note that `harry` cannot see instance variables referenced by `test`: `@a = 'hey'; def test; puts instance_variable_defined?(:@a); end`. Then after defining `harry#test`, `harry.test => false`.

Comment: Is the end result the same as `def harry.test; Object.new.send(:test); end`? In other words, does this create a method `harry#test` that merely invokes `Object#test` on a new instance of `Object`? If so, I don't think "bind" is the right term.

Answer (score 2):

The API you want doesn't easily work, because you have to know from *which scope* you want to access the local variable. It's not quite clear to me why you want to pass the name of the local variable instead of passing the content of the local variable … after all, the local variable *is* present at the call site.

Anyway, if you pass in the scope in addition to the name, this can be accomplished rather easily:

```
def some_method(*args)
  puts args
  puts "I can access some_instance's ivar: #@private_instance_var"
end

class Foo; def initialize; @private_instance_var = :foo end end

some_instance = Foo.new

def method_that_binds(meth, to:, within:, with: [])
  self.class.instance_method(meth).bind(within.local_variable_get(to)).(*with)
end

method_that_binds(:some_method, to: :some_instance, within: binding, with: ['arg1', 'arg2'])
# arg1
# arg2
# I can access some_instance's ivar: foo
```

As you can see, I also added a way to pass arguments to the method. Without that extension, it becomes even simpler:

```
def method_that_binds(meth, to:, within:)
  self.class.instance_method(meth).bind(within.local_variable_get(to)).()
end
```

But you have to pass the scope (`Binding`) into the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to add a method *just* to `some_instance` i.e. it's not available on other instances of `Klass` then this can be done using `define_singleton_method` (documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-define_singleton_method).)

```
some_instance.define_singleton_method(:some_method, method(:some_method))
```

Here the first use of the symbol `:some_method` is the name you'd like the method to have on `some_instance` and the second use as a parameter to `method` is creating a `Method` object from your existing method.

If you'd like to use the same name as the existing method you could wrap this in your own method like:

```
def add_method(obj, name)
  obj.define_singleton_method(name, method(name))
end
```

Comment: The only problem is that `some_instance` is passed as a symbol argument. Can I somehow transform the symbol `:some_instance` to the instance `some_instance`?

Comment: In Ruby 2.1 and later you can use `local_variable_get` to go from the symbol to the instance variable e.g. `local_variable_get(some_instance)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a class `A` with a method `a` and a local variable `c`.

```
class A
  def a; 10 end
end

c = '5'
```

And we want to add the method `A#a` to `c`.

This is how it can be done

```
c.singleton_class.send :define_method, :b, &A.new.method(:a)
p c.b # => 10
```

Explanations.

One way to add a method to an object instance and not to its class is to define it in its singleton class (which every ruby object has).

We can get the `c`'s singleton class by calling the corresponding method `c.signleton_class`.

Next we need to dynamically define a method in its class and this can usually be accomplished by using the `define_method` which takes a method name as its first argument (in our case `:b`) and a block. Now, converting the method into a block might look a bit tricky but the idea is relatively simple: we first transform the method into a `Method` instance by calling the [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-method) and then by putting the `&` before `A.new.method(:a)` we tell the interpreter to call the `to_proc` method on our object (as our returned object is an instance of the `Method`, the [Method#to_proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-to_proc) will be called) and after that the returned proc will be translated into a block that the `define_method` expects as its second argument.

Comment: Please [edit] in an explanation of why/how this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they are not as easy to learn from as code with an explanation. Without an explanation it takes considerably more time and effort to understand what was being done, the changes made to the code, if the code answers the question, etc.  The explanation is important both for people attempting to learn from the answer and those evaluating the answer to see if it is valid, or worth up voting.

Comment: Okay, I added some explanation. The answer doesn't cover how to get a local variable by the symbol as it was covered by other answers but hope it's still useful.